# Any advanced data binding library for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there any library that would let me do stuff like bind a property in an object to the maximum value of two properties in another object? Or bind it to the sum of every occurrence of a particular property inside each object in a list?

Or bind a list to another list such that both lists are synchronized and each element in the target list always has a corresponding element in the source list while a particular property of every object in the source list is bound to a particular property of every element in the target list?

In sum, is there an advanced data binding library? This would make coding so much easier.

I believe WPF has more advanced data binding than WinForms, but in case you were about to suggest me to switch to WPF, I'm working on an already developed WinForms project so I either need an existing library or need to write it myself.

**Update:** I just started [this github](http://github.com/jsoldi/Bindings) that in case anyone else find it useful. It still needs lots of work to be done but is already usable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft Reactive Extensions library ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx ) isn't UI specific but may provide a middle layer to help you achieve a lot of the goals you stated.